# Removing date from datetime (VBA Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, date-time, extract

I need to delete the date from mulitple rows with a datetime value. Or extract the time to another cell.

For example:

```
A1 = 3/11/2022 10:20:00
A1 after macro = 10:20:00
or
A1 = 3/11/2022 10:20:00
A2 = 10:20:00
```

If I change the number format, the cell will display the time (10:20:00) but the cell value is still 3/11/2022 10:20:00. I need the time for a batch upload and therefore need to remove the date. 
 The following code worked for me. But only for one cell. If i chanced the range to "A1:A5" for example I would get an error.

```vb
Sub ChangeDateToTime()
With Range("A1")
    .Value = TimeValue(.Value)
    .NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
End With
End Sub
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: A quicker way to do this might be to use TextToColumns, with a delimiter on ` ` (space).

Comment: How are you doing the "batch upload"? Is this copy/paste from one Excel workbook to another?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need VBA for that, as the time can be moved to another
column with the following formula.

Assuming that the date-times column is A starting at row 1, set the
the column (for example) B1 to the following:

```
=TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))
```

Now you may click inside B1, then drag the bottom-right corner down
over the B column to extend the formula.

---

A neat trick brought to my attention below by Ron Rosenfeld for
extracting the time-part from a datetime value, is to use a formula
based on the MOD function.

This formula in B1 is simpler:

```
=MOD(A1,1)
```

For more details about this trick, see the article
[Extract time from a date and time](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-time-from-a-date-and-time)

Comment: Why not `=mod(a1,1)` ?